# Get mid of Y Axis of chart

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

I have a chart like below:

[image]

I need to add a horizontal line which should be at mid of chart (over 50 in this case)
Is there an easy way to do it?

I tried below code but doesn't give correct result (y property)

```
y = ch.Parent.top + ch.PlotArea.top + (ch.PlotArea.Height / 2)
```

Comment: Why not add the line as a series?

Comment: @TimWilliams I'm copying this chart from Excel to PPT. Need to add this line in PPT only directly as per the requirements